# VS2019 Debugger fails after renaming ClientApp folder in dotnet core angular app

Tags: angular, asp.net-core, visual-studio-2019

This question is similar to [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55124808/dotnet-core-2-1-angular-app-rename-clientapp-folder). But the solutions to the other question prevent breakpoints from being set in the modified app.

I have Visual Studio Pro 2019 Preview Version 16.3.0 Preview 2.0 and .Net Core 3.0.100-preview8-013656.

1. Run "dotnet new angular"
2. Set a Typescript breakpoint in VS2019. Press F5 and check that it gets hit.
3. Change name of Angular folder from ClientApp to XClientApp
4. Make these changes in startup.cs:

   ```
   configuration.RootPath = "XClientApp/dist";
   ...
   spa.Options.SourcePath = "XClientApp";
   ```
5. Make this change in the project file:

   ```
   <SpaRoot>XClientApp\</SpaRoot>
   ```
6. Delete current node_modules folder - because during the "npm install", the absolute location of the Angular app folder gets hardcoded into many packages in about 2,000 places.
7. Set a Typescript breakpoint in VS2019. Press F5 and observe that it is NOT hit.
8. See open circle by breakpoint with error:

   ```
   "The breakpoint will not currently be hit. Breakpoint set but not yet bound."
   ```

Besides where it creates the "ClientApp" folder, where else does the SPA template have this string hardcoded into its code. And is there anyway to override this default?

[PS: My main goal is to put the WebApp code and the Angular code in seperate folders "Backend" and "Frontend". I tried first just changing the name, because I know that if I can't even change the folder name, there is no way I will be able to change the folder location. ]

**Added info**: I searched the source code for the angular spa template on GitHub. I found this additional reference to "ClientApp" in "AspNetCore\src\ProjectTemplates\Web.Spa.ProjectTemplates\content\Angular-CSharp.template.config\template.json".
In sources -> modifiers -> exclude:

```
    "ClientApp/src/api-authorization/**",
```

**More extra info**: If I (1) run the app with F5, (2) press F12 in the Chrome Browser, (3) set a breakpoint using the Chrome Dev Tools, (4) hit & clear the breakpoint, then breakpoints will start working in Visual Studio. But I don't want to go through this each time to get breakpoints working.

Comment: Try deleting the `.vs` folder to make sure that there isn’t something cached about the old location.

Comment: @poke Thanks for the suggestion. But no, the problem still remains.

Comment: Have you enabled the setting in vs 2019? `Tools > Options > Debugging > General > Enable Javascript debugging for ASP.NET (Chomre, Edge and IE)` ?

Comment: @Zze Yes that option is already enabled. Also debugging worked fine until I changed the name of the folder.

Comment: @JohnPankowicz Did you ever resolve this?

Comment: @Zze No, it is still un-resolved. I opened an issue at https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-chrome-debug-core/issues/522 but no-one has taken a look at it yet. Perhaps if you add a comment there, it will increase in priority.